# number of repetitions of a substring

Tags: regex, r

I have a string and i am finding consecutive repeating substring for atleast 3 times in it, allowing a wildcard character.
i want to find out how many times is it repeating. i can not use stingr package because of wildcard character.
For eg:
suppose the string is

```
abcdabcdabcb
```

then output is abcd.

```
ababacab
```

output-ab

```
pqrprrpqr
```

output- pqr

i want to calculate how many times is it repeating. How can i do that?
For above examples, answer for first one is 3, then 4, for last one also 3

Comment: Are you specifying the substring to check for repeats & counts or do you want it detected (like in @Avinash's answer)?

Comment: What do you mean by wildcard character?

Comment: like at one position of a substring character can be anything. suppose a string jkljkljkkghdn, here jkl i am outputting.

Comment: I don't really understand your output.  There are many more repeated strings if you look at all the substrings

Comment: like, tell me one example so that i can clear your doubt.

Comment: I am so sorry, my bad, it must be 4. And pqr does. see i have a code which neglects one character if missing out of whole substring. Suppose tyutyptyu. It will neglect p and take it as u, because requirement is that

Comment: So it actually in not a repetition in the string

Comment: it is, but allows any character at 1 position.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this kind of pattern:

```
(?|
    (([a-z]+)[a-z]([a-z]*))(?:\2[a-z]\3){2,}
  | 
    ([a-z]([a-z]+))(?:[a-z]\2){2,}
)
```

[online demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/ui9C4G8afrrG0soH)

Comment: great answer. Thanks, but it will output substring which is included in another. That is of no use.

Comment: Also, how can i use it on Rstudio

Comment: @user4016111: two possible ways: 1) you use str_match from stringr package (that gives you the capture groups). 2) you replace  non-capturing groups with lookaheads.

Comment: Thank you, i'l try. and no. of repetitions?

Comment: str_match won't help becuase pattern we don't know prior to inputting the string neither it is an exact one.